# When using onDrag in SwiftUI on Mac how can I detect when the dragged object has been released anywhere?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I have a list of items which i am able to drag and drop. When picking up the item it's hidden and i want to it to be revealed again on released wherever even outside the app window.

Im using onDrag and am yet to find a way to detect when the item is released except when in a .drop area.